# MySQL stored proc syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Trying to implement a simple nested loop routine  in mysql:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE days_cnt INT;

    SET days_cnt = 0; # Start today
    WHILE days_cnt < 10 DO

        WHILE 1 DO

        END WHILE;

        SET days_cnt = days_cnt + 1;
    END WHILE;

END
```

This is giving a generic 1064 error about a syntax error near 'END WHILE;'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you need to redefine the delimiter (semi-colon) as it's within a stored program. As per [Defining Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

So add the following (it can be any character(s) other than a semi-colon) before your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement: `delimiter $$`

And then reset it after the `CREATE PROCEDURE` ends: `delimiter ;`

Otherwise, I'm not sure how MySQL handles an empty `WHILE` loop statement (the `WHILE 1 DO END` part) which you've got nested in your outer `WHILE` loop. You may want to remove that or process whatever it is you need to in that inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

This loop must have a statement inside of it:

```
WHILE 1 DO

END WHILE;
```